# Generating CSV file download from data-URI; issue in IE9 as it saves as UCS 2 LE instead of UTF-8

Tags: javascript, csv, character-encoding, internet-explorer-9, data-uri

I am trying to generate CSV data using JavaScript and prompt the user to save it as a CSV file.

The code works fine in IE10+ and other browsers, but I also need to support IE9.

In IE9, the resulting CSV file is displayed in Excel like this:

[image]

In other words, it looks like it somehow doesn't pick up the commas as separators. This can be fixed by adding the line that you can see commented out in the code below, but then the non-Roman characters in the file appear garbled.

When opening the CSV file in Notepad++, I noticed that the encoding of the file produced by IE9 is UCS-2 LE, which is different from UTF-8 file produced by other browsers:

[image]

Just to check,  I opened the file in Vim and saw the UCS-2 LE byte order mark (`fffe fffe`):

[image]

If I click UTF-8 in that menu and save the file, Excel displays the CSV file normally. Therefore I assume that the root of the issue is that IE9 saves the file with a wrong encoding.

Is there some way I can force IE9 to use UTF-8 instead of UCS-2 LE, or otherwise make this code work in IE9 to download CSV data from data URI as file?

```
var file = getCSVdata();
var filename = getShortDateString() + "_search_results.csv";

var link = document.createElement('a');

//This is for modern browsers - works fine
if (typeof link.download === 'string') { 
    link.href = file;
    link.target = "_new";
    link.onclick = "return false";
    link.download = filename;

    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

} 
//Here we go...
else {
    //IE10+
    if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        file = decodeURIComponent(
            file.replace("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,",""));

        var blob = new Blob([file], { 
            type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
        });
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    }
    else { //IE9 - this doesn't work 
        var iframe = document.getElementById('csvDownloadFrame');
        iframe = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument;

        //get pure CSV data without the data-uri prefix
        file = decodeURIComponent(
                   file.replace("data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,",""));

        //file = 'sep=,\r' + file; //if uncomment this, then CSV file recognized columns normally, but garbles the non-Roman alphabet characters

        iframe.document.open("text/csv", "replace");
        iframe.document.write(file);
        iframe.document.close();
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Simply stop support old IE9 like Microsoft will do on jan 12 2016 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support

Comment: @Endless That was a year ago and many, including banks, will still use IE9 for years to come. You're obviously not working in the software industry. Thanks for your valuable advice.

Comment: Oh I work with software alright and have been doing so for 8 years not just only with web. Today only 0.37% of Sweden use ie9. And ie8 was not even on the map of  [ga.statcounter](http://ga.statcounter.com) ... (ie8 worldwide 0.8%) (ie9 worldwide 0.53%) We don't spend resources/money/time to maintain a old version of ie that nobody barliy uses any longer

Comment: and no IE9 will not be around for year**s** to come it's almost already completely dead probably in 1 year it's down at 0%

Comment: @Endless Stackoverflow is not a place for this discussion, but since nobody's watching... Dude, don't be ridiculuous. I don't care about the 0.53% of users in Sweden because 100% of our users use IE9. If a customer is a corporation, they only have one browser on tens of thousands of machines, and they're not upgrading any time soon.